# C++ Qt5 - Program finishes before QThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

Let's take a look at the following code:

```
class CommandRetriever
{
    public:
        CommandRetriever();
        ~CommandRetriever();
    
        void addCommand( QString, Command* );
        void executeCommands();

    private:
        QMap<QString, Command*> m_commands;
};
```

`addCommand` should be self-explanatory; it will add a new entry into `m_commands`. However, let's take a look at the implementation of `executeCommands`...

```
void CommandRetriever::executeCommands()
{
    for( auto iter : m_commands.keys() )
    {
        Command *cmd = m_commands.value( iter ); 
         
        // Command, password //
        RemoteConnection *rcon = new RemoteConnection( cmd, "" );

        QThread *thread = new QThread();
        rcon->moveToThread( thread );
        QObject::connect( thread, SIGNAL( started() ), rcon, SLOT( doAsync() ) );
        QObject::connect( rcon, SIGNAL( finished() ), thread, SLOT( quit() ) );
        QObject::connect( rcon, SIGNAL( finished() ), rcon, SLOT( deleteLater() ) );
        QObject::connect( thread, SIGNAL( finished() ), thread, SLOT( deleteLater() ) );
        thread->start();
    }
}
```

My `rcon` object is a QObject which has the public slot `doAsync()` to do work off the main thread. All of this is per Qt official examples and what I was able to muster from various blogs.

This is a completely console-based program, so I have no Windows, Widgets, or event loops to work with.

---

### The Problem

What happens is that my program will exit before any asynchronous work is able to be done (e.g. connect to a remote host, write data, etc). Sometimes, if I'm lucky, my threads will do work fast enough to output something, so I know that the threads are working as they should. My question is: **How do I keep my main program running until my threads finish the work?** Is there an official way of doing this in `QThread`? Because I haven't seen anything in the docs.

Thanks!

---

### Addendum April 20, 2015

Although the accepted answer made by Jeremy in this question is correct, it makes less sense for console-based applications, where an event loop is typically not needed.

Thus, I asked a new question, and found an answer for those in search of using threads without Qt event loop non-sense:

[QThread never quits due to QCoreApplication event loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640753/qthread-never-quits-due-to-qcoreapplication-event-loop)

Comment: Possible duplicate of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324017/making-the-main-thread-wait-till-all-other-qthread-finished

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you are looking for is QThread::wait().  Call it on each thread object, from your main thread, before starting your program's cleanup/exit stage.  It will wait until the thread has exited before returning.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply... but how would this work with multiple threads? Would I put it in the `for` loop? Or would I keep track of all of the threads in a map (or another container) and wait for all of the threads to finish?

Comment: The latter -- put the wait() calls into a separate for-loop.  Putting the wait() call in the same for loop would mean that thread #2 wouldn't get launched until after thread #1 had exited, which would defeat the purpose of spawning threads.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I'll update my question with the implemented solution and accept the answer when I can.

Comment: Jeremy; my `QThread::wait()` functions block the main thread and never return. Can you help me out?

Comment: Most likely the thread is never exiting.  Does quit() ever get called in the thread?