# QThread never quits due to QCoreApplication event loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

### Problem

So I have a CommandRetriever class that holds some commands, and *should* execute these commands on different threads.

```
class CommandRetriever
{
    public:
        CommandRetriever();
        ~CommandRetriever();
    
        void addCommand( QString, Command* );
        void executeCommands();

    private:
        QMap<QString, Command*> m_commands;
};
```

`addCommand` will add a new entry into `m_commands`. Here is the function in question, however.

```
void CommandRetriever::executeCommands()
{
    for( auto iter : m_commands.keys() )
    {
        Command *cmd = m_commands.value( iter ); 
         
        // Command, password //
        RemoteConnection *rcon = new RemoteConnection( cmd, "" );

        QThread *thread = new QThread();
        rcon->moveToThread( thread );
        QObject::connect( thread, SIGNAL( started() ), rcon, SLOT( doAsync() ) );
        QObject::connect( rcon, SIGNAL( finished() ), thread, SLOT( quit() ) );
        QObject::connect( rcon, SIGNAL( finished() ), rcon, SLOT( deleteLater() ) );
        QObject::connect( thread, SIGNAL( finished() ), thread, SLOT( deleteLater() ) );
        thread->start();
    }
}
```

`RemoteConnection` is my worker thread. The `doAsync()` slot is what processes what needs to be processed.

For some reason, my `doAsync()` function for my `rcon` object will be called, but the thread will never exit... my main class looks like this:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{           
    QCoreApplication app( argc, argv );     
    CommandRetriever cr( addr, port );

    //cr.addCommand() ...

    cr.executeCommands();

    return app.exec();
}
```

My worker objects (`rcon`) will output what they're supposed to. However, even though my worker objects emit a `finished()` signal, the thread still lives, and my application never finishes. I connected a signal like this before:

```
QObject::connect( rcon, SIGNAL( finished() ), thread, SLOT( deleteLater() ) );
```

But then I got the error: `QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running` and a seg fault.

I recently posted a question that had a related issue to my threads, and the solution was to call `thread->wait()`, however, I saw that if I have an event loop, `thread->wait()` is not needed, and is not an appropriate solution. With the current code, I get no error, but my application runs forever. I'm guessing the `app.exec()` event loop is infinitely running, and if I'm right, how can I shut everything down correctly?

---

### Solution

As thuga said:

> You need to tell your QCoreApplication to quit, otherwise it will never return from the exec function.

This could easily be achieved by connecting a my worker object's `finished()` signal to make my app quit:

```
QObject::connect( rcon, SIGNAL( finished() ), app, SLOT( quit() ) );
```

However, this makes more sense if I had a window or some other GUI elements so that I would be able to definitively know when I need to shut down my program (e.g. the user closes the main window).

Because I was running multiple threads and because my application is only a console application, it didn't make sense to connect my thread's `finished()` signal to my `QCoreApplication`'s `quit()` slot. So what I ended up using was `QThreadPool`:

```
void CommandRetriever::executeCommands()
{
     // Quick iterate through the command map //
    for( auto iter : m_commands.keys() )
    {     
        Command *cmd = m_commands.value( iter ); 

         // Command, password; start a new thread for a remote connection. //
        RemoteConnection *rcon = new RemoteConnection( cmd, "" );
        QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start( rcon );
    }
}
```

It should be noted that the class RemoteConnection extends `QRunnable`.

To wait for the threads to finish, I call:

```
QThreadPool::globalInstance()->waitForDone();
```

This will block the main thread until all of the threads finish execution, which makes more sense for my console application. It also makes the code a hell of a lot cleaner.

I also removed `app.exec()` in my main.cpp because I no longer needed the event loop that `QCoreApplication` provides.

What I learned? `QThread` isn't the only way to achieve multithreading. In my case, it makes more sense to use `QThreadPool` because I didn't need the signals/slots of `QThread`. Also, you shouldn't use the `QCoreApplication` event loop if it is not needed. Most console applications will fall into this category.

---

### Sources

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrunnable.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthreadpool.html

Comment: does your `RemoteConnection` object finish the job / emit `finished()`?
in case of your error message, store the pointers to the thread objects and call `QThread::wait()` in destructor to ensure

Comment: How do you know that the thread still lives? You need to tell your `QCoreApplication` to quit, otherwise it will never return from the `exec` function.

Comment: @thuga In this case, how would I tell my application to quit?

Comment: You can connect a signal to the [`QCoreApplication::quit()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#quit) slot.

Comment: There is a good explanation of different threading technologies in the [docs here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html#choosing-an-appropriate-approach).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't tell your `QCoreApplication` object to quit, it will never leave the `exec()` function.

You can either call `QCoreApplication::quit()` slot directly, or connect a signal to it.

```
...
connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));
```

`qApp` is a global pointer referring to the unique application object. It's same as calling `QCoreApplication::instance()`.

Comment: This is correct, although it makes more sense for programs for a UI. I instead switched from `QThread` to `QThreadPool` and made my RemoteConnection extend `QRunnable`.

Comment: Because this answer is correct, I accepted it- although a more comprehensive solution is in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting the `finished()` signal of the `RemoteConnection` to the `terminate()` slot of the `QThread` instead of the `quit()` slot.

```
QObject::connect( rcon, SIGNAL( finished() ), thread, SLOT( terminate() ) );
```

The thread may or may not be terminated immediately, depending on the operating system's scheduling policies. Use `QThread::wait()` after `terminate()`, to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a new QCoreApplication object at the initializer of your dll class "CommandRetriever", then call: processEvents, once. as follow:

```
//Create the QCoreApplication object
int argc = 1;
char * argv[] = {"my.dll", NULL};
dllEventHandler = new QCoreApplication(argc, argv);
//Start: process events
dllEventHandler->processEvents();
```

That is all. Your don't need main function or QCoreApplication .exec().