# Call a slot only when n number of signals are emitted?

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qt-signals

Is it possible to connect more than 1 signal to a slot in a way that the slot gets called only when all the related signals are emitted?

Comment: It's not immediately clear here as to what you are trying to do. We can help you alot easier if you post some sort of example.

Comment: I have two separate threads running concurrent functions and each emit a signal on completion. In my main thread is a function that I would like to run after the other two functions running in separate threads are finished.  This is a very generic concept based question. I can think of hacks around it, just trying to figure out if the framework supports it in an easier way.

Comment: @DjokerS QThread::wait maybe? It sounds like you want the equivalent of a join. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324017/making-the-main-thread-wait-till-all-other-qthread-finished

Comment: I was looking to see if there's anything at the framework level. I understand and agree with the counter/tracking slots to handle specific cases, just not the generic one. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

you can first emit the all signals to a other slot,then in that slot you receive all the signals and when all signals come you emit the signal to the slot you want eventually.